# Passing dataframe to function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to pass df to function for further manipulation. When I read dataframe into function from csv then it works (function sees it as df):

```
    import_data <- function(filename){
  (filename1 <-paste(filename, ".csv", sep=""))
  filename= data.frame(read.csv(filename1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
#additional manipulation here
  return(filename)
}
```

But when i try to send existing df to function then it doesn't work.

```
 age_adjust <- function(dfname, category, agecat, interest){
  temp1=dfname
#additional manipulation here
  return(temp1)
}
```

Also, tried several other iterations to have the function "see" this as a df to no avail:

```
age_adjust <- function(dfname, category, agecat, interest){
  temp1=dfname.copy()
#additional manipulation here
  return(temp1)
}

age_adjust <- function(dfname, category, agecat, interest){
  temp1=data.frame(dfname)
#additional manipulation here
  return(temp1)
}
```

I tried to look at many answers and to no avail. There are many calculations that I have to run on several similar columns and having these run through a function would be much easier. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out: need to pass the name without quotations (when calling function). Age_adjust(d2019) instead of Age_adjust("d2019")